# Where and how put my business logic in django

Tags: django, django-models, logic, business-logic

A friend recommended that I read the book two scoops Django and I was amazed at the recommendations he makes for a robust and well-designed Django project. This reading created a doubt in me and it is where I put the business logic, I give an example. Suppose I have two models:

> models.py

```
class Sparks(models.Model):
    flavor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Frozen(models.Model):
    flavor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    has_cone = models.BooleanField()
    quantity_sparks = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Let's suppose that every time I add a frozen, if it has sparks, I have to subtract it from the `Sparks` model and check that there is an available quantity. In the book they recommend putting this logic in `models.py` or `forms.py`. If create some model required modify data from another model where should I do it?

Comment: What is the nature of the relationship between Frozen and Sparks. If you normalize your data model, your question/concern goes away.

Comment: @schillingt this is just an example. If create some model required modify data from another model where should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your data model is lacking, that's the likely source of uneasiness.

```
class Flavor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Sparks(model.Model):
    flavor = models.ForeignKeyField(Flavor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Frozen(model.Model):
    # This maybe should be a OneToOne, can't tell from your description.
    sparks = models.ForeignKeyField(Sparks)
    has_cone = models.BooleanField()
```

Then you'd do

```
frozen_instance = Frozen.objects.get()
frozen.sparks.quantity # This has replaced frozen_instance.quantity_sparks
```